# Woocommerce add custom dropdown-field to checkout and show in backend (order)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use the following code to add a custom field to the WooCommerce checkout. The field is showing in the checkout process but in the backend the value is always empty.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'dropdown' );

function dropdown( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['advice'] = array(
      'label'     => __('Type', 'woocommerce'),
      'placeholder'   => _x('Type', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
      'required'  => true,
      'priority'   => 80,
      'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
      'clear'     => true,
      'type'      => 'select',
      'options'     => array(
          'se' => __('SE-Term', 'woocommerce' ),
          'ab' => __('AB-Term', 'woocommerce' ),
          'pp' => __('PP-Term', 'woocommerce' )
        )
      );
      return $fields;
  }

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta' );
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
  echo '<p><strong>'.__('Terminart:').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'advice', true ) . '</p>';
}
```